# CSS style on link tag

Tags: css

Hi I would like to make my `<a>` tag react on the full height and width of the parent li.

How can I achieve this? Display block doesn't work. Putting it around the li instead of inside removes the last li for some reason.

As requested here's the relevant code.

```
nav li{height:70px;float:left;margin:0px;padding:25px 20px;display:block;}
nav li:hover{background:#00A2E5;}
nav a, nav a:visited{font:bold 20px Arial;color:#515151;text-decoration:none;display:block;}
nav a:hover, nav a:visited:hover{font:;color:#FFFFFF;}
```

Comment: can you place some of your codes with css.It will more helpful to solve this.

Comment: `display: block` should work, are you sure you also set `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` on the `<a>` tag ?

Comment: `display:inline-block;`... maybe?

Comment: Yeah that was the answer, thought that came automaticaly with display block

Comment: The width comes with `display: block` but the height doesn't. That is the important part. Look at other block elements. They always have maximum width and minimum height. There is an exception, though: floating elements. They always have everything as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li a {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: +1, but you should probably add `display: block;` as well. It is not going to work without it.

Comment: Thx, can't accept the answer until in 9 minutes, but you'll get credit.

Comment: This doesn't work for height?  And for width it will make the link the entire screen width instead of the width of the parent. You have to set height explicitly and the width will automatically be inherited, don't set it.

Comment: @Stefan Yes it does work for height, and width gets the width of the parent. Not the entire screen (unless there is no parent). I guess you don't use height:100% because you never got it to work, try html,body{height:100%;} and see what happens.

Comment: @hustlerinc: Confirmed...  didn't need to set html or body styles.  Demo here, for the record: http://jsfiddle.net/StefanCoetzee/nptUe/